# AddEventListener with in a object

Tags: javascript, html, this, addeventlistener

I could need your help, at the moment I am trying to call a method within a object through a addEventListener activation. The problem is that the this pointer is changing as soon as the method get called. I tried to use the .call to give the method the right context back and it worked as expected but is this the best way ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Java Script Test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <!-- <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script> -->
        <script src="../resurces/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" ></script>
        <script>
            var test_class = function(){
                this.variable = "more text";
                this.click = function(){
                    $("#return").text("Content: "+this.variable);
                }
                this.aktivate_listener = function(){
                    var that = this;
                    document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", function(){that.click.call(that)});
                }

            }

            $("document").ready(function(){
                console.log("#ready");
                var class1 = new test_class();
                class1.aktivate_listener();

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="clicker">This is some Text to click on.</p>
        <p id="return"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Do some of you know a better way ?

Thanks for your effort ,
Flo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's mostly fine, but a couple of points:

1. You don't need to do `that.click.call(that)` — simply `that.click()` will work.
2. You're not passing on the event object that your anonymous function receives. If you don't need it, that's fine, but I thought I'd mention it.

Another alternative is to use [`Function#bind`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.5):

```
this.aktivate_listener = function(){
    document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", this.click.bind(this));
}
```

`Function#bind` returns a function that, when called, turns around and calls the original function with `this` set to a specific value. So `this.click.bind(this)` creates a function that, when called, will call `click` on the object with `this` referring to the object. Any arguments to the bound function are passed on when it calls the underlying function.

---

Re your comment:

> But I read that you can't remove an EventListener that is created with .bind `A problem in the example above is that you cannot remove the listener with bind`. *That is taken from the Mozilla Developer Network.*

If so, MDN is wrong. It's community-edited, that happens. :-)

In terms of being able to remove the handler with `removeEventListener`, there's no difference **at all** between your code and using `Function#bind` as above: You can't remove the listener in either case without changing the code to remember what we passed to `addEventListener`.

There's nothing special about event handlers that use `bind`. Just like any other event handler, if you want to remove it with `removeEventListener`, you have to have a reference to the **same function** you added when removing it. In your code, that would be the anonymous function that you have wrapped around `that.click.call(that);`, and since you didn't keep a reference to it, you can't remove it. Similarly, in my code above, you can't remove the listener because I didn't keep a reference to the bound function.

If that's something you need to do, just remember the function you want to remove — that's a reference to your anonymous function, or a reference to the function returned by `Function#bind`. You might store it on your object, for instance.

```
this.aktivate_listener = function(){
    if (this.boundClick) {
        this.deaktivate_listener();
    }
    this.boundClick = this.click.bind(this);
    document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", this.boundClick);
};
this.deacktivate_listener = function(){
    document.getElementById("clicker").removeEventListener("click", this.boundClick);
    this.boundClick = null;
};
```

---

Looking again at your code, you have a third option: Your `click` function is a closure over the call to `test_class` that created the instance, so you don't need to create another closure, just use the one you already have:

```
var test_class = function(){
    // Remember `this` in a variable
    var self = this;
    this.variable = "more text";
    this.click = function(){
        // Use it here
        $("#return").text("Content: "+self.variable);
    };
    this.aktivate_listener = function(){
        // Just use `this.click` here
        document.getElementById("clicker").addEventListener("click", this.click);
    };
    this.deaktivate_listener = function(){
        // Just use `this.click` here
        document.getElementById("clicker").removeEventListener("click", this.click);
    };
};
```

---

Side note: You need a `;` at the end of statements like `var f = function() { };`, because those are statements, not declarations. I've added them above. If you don't provide it, Automatic Semicolon Insertion will add it for you most of the time, but you can trip up if you're not careful.

---

**Examples of all of the above:**

Your way without `.call` (without deaktivate):

```js
var Test = function(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.click = function() {
    snippet.log("My name is " + this.name);
  };
  this.aktivate_listener = function() {
    var that = this;
    document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener(
      "click",
      function() { that.click(); },
      false
    );
  };
};
var t1 = new Test("one", "test one");
t1.aktivate_listener();
var t2 = new Test("two", "test two");
t2.aktivate_listener();
```

```html
<div id="one">Click me (one)</div>
<div id="two">Click me (two)</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

With `Function#bind` (without deaktivate):

```js
var Test = function(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.click = function() {
    snippet.log("My name is " + this.name);
  };
  this.aktivate_listener = function() {
    document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener(
      "click",
      this.click.bind(this),
      false
    );
  };
};
var t1 = new Test("one", "test one");
t1.aktivate_listener();
var t2 = new Test("two", "test two");
t2.aktivate_listener();
```

```html
<div id="one">Click me (one)</div>
<div id="two">Click me (two)</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Using the existing closure (without deaktivate):

```js
var Test = function(id, name) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.click = function() {
    snippet.log("My name is " + self.name);
  };
  this.aktivate_listener = function() {
    document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener(
      "click",
      this.click,
      false
    );
  };
};
var t1 = new Test("one", "test one");
t1.aktivate_listener();
var t2 = new Test("two", "test two");
t2.aktivate_listener();
```

```html
<div id="one">Click me (one)</div>
<div id="two">Click me (two)</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Your way without `.call` (with deaktivate):

```js
var Test = function(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.counter = 0;
  this.click = function() {
    snippet.log("My name is " + this.name);
    if (++this.counter == 2) {
      this.deaktivate_listener();
    };
  };
  this.aktivate_listener = function() {
    var that = this;
    if (this.boundClick) {
      this.deaktivate_listener();
    }
    this.boundClick = function() { that.click(); };
    document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener(
      "click",
      this.boundClick,
      false
    );
  };
  this.deaktivate_listener = function() {
    if (this.boundClick) {
      document.getElementById(this.id).removeEventListener(
        "click",
        this.boundClick,
        false
      );
      this.boundClick = null;
    }
  };
};
var t1 = new Test("one", "test one");
t1.aktivate_listener();
var t2 = new Test("two", "test two");
t2.aktivate_listener();
```

```html
<div id="one">Click me (one) (second click deactivates)</div>
<div id="two">Click me (two) (second click deactivates)</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

With `Function#bind` (with deaktivate):

```js
var Test = function(id, name) {
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.counter = 0;
  this.click = function() {
    snippet.log("My name is " + this.name);
    if (++this.counter == 2) {
      this.deaktivate_listener();
    };
  };
  this.aktivate_listener = function() {
    if (this.boundClick) {
      this.deaktivate_listener();
    }
    this.boundClick = this.click.bind(this);
    document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener(
      "click",
      this.boundClick,
      false
    );
  };
  this.deaktivate_listener = function() {
    if (this.boundClick) {
      document.getElementById(this.id).removeEventListener(
        "click",
        this.boundClick,
        false
      );
      this.boundClick = null;
    }
  };
};
var t1 = new Test("one", "test one");
t1.aktivate_listener();
var t2 = new Test("two", "test two");
t2.aktivate_listener();
```

```html
<div id="one">Click me (one) (second click deactivates)</div>
<div id="two">Click me (two) (second click deactivates)</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Using the existing closure (with deaktivate):

```js
var Test = function(id, name) {
  var self = this;
  this.id = id;
  this.name = name;
  this.counter = 0;
  this.click = function() {
    snippet.log("My name is " + self.name);
    if (++self.counter == 2) {
      self.deaktivate_listener();
    };
  };
  this.aktivate_listener = function() {
    document.getElementById(this.id).addEventListener(
      "click",
      this.click,
      false
    );
  };
  this.deaktivate_listener = function() {
    document.getElementById(this.id).removeEventListener(
      "click",
      this.click,
      false
    );
  };
};
var t1 = new Test("one", "test one");
t1.aktivate_listener();
var t2 = new Test("two", "test two");
t2.aktivate_listener();
```

```html
<div id="one">Click me (one) (second click deactivates)</div>
<div id="two">Click me (two) (second click deactivates)</div>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: If I am removing the .call it does not work, I think that it is loosing the pointer again. But I read that you can't remove an EventListener that is created with .bind `A problem in the example above is that you cannot remove the listener with bind.` _That is taken from the Mozilla Developer Network_.

Comment: @Feirell: If so, MDN is wrong. I've updated the answer to discuss it.

Comment: @Feirell: *"If I am removing the .call it does not work"* It would with the quoted code. It doesn't "lose" `this`; `that.click()` will call `click` with `this` set to `that` during the call.

Comment: @Feirell: I've added examples of all of the discussed options above. Enjoy!

Comment: This is amazing, wow, to be honest no one ever gave that great response, thanks a lot ! Ok I think I understood how to assign and remove the EventListerner, to add parameters for the click method I can just add .call like this:  `this.boundClick = this.click.bind(this).call(this, arg);` or ?

Comment: @Feirell: :-) Glad that helped. You can actually burn arguments in with `bind`: `this.boundClick = this.click.bind(this, arg1, arg2);` When `this.boundClick` is called, the args it gets are the ones you bound followed by any supplied when it was called. E.g., `var f = function(a, b, c) { ... }; var fb = f.bind(this, 1); fb(2, 3);` will call `f` with `a = 1`, `b = 2`, and `c = 3`.

Comment: Wow you are amazing that helped me so much ! I am going to write this in the original code and I am gonna try to assign it like you to, would you read over it when I am finished ? _the projekt where I need this (not this clicker thing)_

Comment: @Feirell: I'm afraid I can't really get into code review. But I'm sure you'll be fine. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the version I use at the moment, it is made of @T.J. Crowder answers.

```
function boxOperator(){
    this.event      = [];

    this.addEvent = function(element, event, tocall_function, arg){         
        var call_function = tocall_function.bind(this, arg);
        this.event[this.event.length] = {
            "element"       : element,
            "event"         : event,
            "call_function" : call_function
        };
        document.getElementById(element).addEventListener(event,call_function);
    };

    this.removeEvent = function(element, event){
        if(!element){return false;};
        var remove_entry = function(index, array){return array.slice(0,index-1).concat(array.slice(index+1));}
        for(var i = 0; i < this.event.length;i++){
            if(this.event[i].element == element){
                var entry = this.event[i];
                if(entry.event == event){
                    document.getElementById(entry.element).removeEventListener(entry.event,entry.call_function);
                    this.event = remove_entry(i, this.event);
                }               
                if(typeof event == "undefined"){
                    document.getElementById(entry.element).removeEventListener(entry.event,entry.call_function);                
                    this.event = remove_entry(i, this.event);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```